# How to run Metro Bundler in VS Code integrated terminal instead of running a new window?

Tags: react-native, visual-studio-code, metro-bundler

I am running npx scripts to build in VS Code integrated terminal, but Metro Bundler runs in new cmd/bash terminal. How to run it in VS Code integrated terminal?

Answer (score 3):

First close all the Metro server, and then Open a new terminal in VS code and then run the command

```js
npx react-native start
```

or

```js
npm start
```

Comment: This doesn't work, or you haven't explained it well enough. I close the terminal window where Metro is running, then from VS Code terminal I do yarn start. I get this: error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081.

Comment: he said to close all Metro servers, not to close all windows on which it is running. When in doubt, run a `sudo pkill -9 node`, it always works.

Comment: This doesn't work. If you do this you get the behaviour OP is talking about where the metro bundler launches in another window.